# Convert \x3c/div\x3e to <div> using perl

Tags: perl, decode

I have a string which has characters like `\x3c/div\x3e` , i am trying to convert this to `<div>` is there any module which helps to solve this issue. I have checked `use HTML::Entities` but couldn't solve the issue, i am in need of some suggestion.

Comment: I imagine there would be other sequences to convert too (`\\ ` -> `\ `)

Comment: @ikegami : could you please explain a little more information about it?

Comment: I'm saying it's likely you haven't fully explained what needs to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method:

```
my $str = '\x3c/div\x3e';

$str =~ s{\\x([[:xdigit:]]{2})}{chr hex $1}eg;

print $str;
```

Outputs

```
<div>
```